# Pm2 issue - fs.readfilesync file not found when procces started from ecosystem.config.js

Tags: node.js, linux, pm2

I am running 2 node apps in GVM instance. in both of them i am loading some SSL certificates. if the apps are run seperately everything is fine ( pm2 start path/to/server.js )

but when i am creating an ecosystem.config.js and trying to start both servers i get a node error file not found.

my ecosystem file :

```
module.exports = {
apps:[
{ name:"ServerProd",
script: "./backend/server.js" },
{name:"SocketProd",
script:"./socket/WSserver.js"}
]
}
```

tried resolving the file with (./filename) (path.join(**dir** + ./filename) and just (filename) all result the same. What am i missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparenty the issue is my folder structure. pm2 ecosystem file is somehow passing root directory to nodejs instances. i managed to solve this by adding the "cwd" option to my ecosystem file.
so :

```
apps:[
{ 
name:"ServerProd",
script: "./backend/server.js" 
},
{
name:"SocketProd",
script:"./socket/WSserver.js"}
]
}
```

became :

```
module.exports = {
apps:[
{ 
name:"ServerProd",
script: "server.js",
cwd:"./backend/" 
},
{
name:"SocketProd",
script:"WSserver.js",
cwd:"./socket/"}
]
}
```

and everything works as expected